# How to alter the below table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlcmd

I have a table like Below

```
**ID Value1  Value2**

 11 AAAA    ZZZZ

 11 A134    ZZZZ

 12 BBBB    YYYY

 12 B222    YYYY

 13 CCCC    XXXX

 13 A134    XXXX
```

And I need the result as Below

ID  Value1  Value2

```
11  AAAA    ZZZZ

12  BBBB    YYYY

13  CCCC    XXXX
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: What's the logic for which values are retained? Is this purely changing the result of selecting from the table or are you wanting to permanently change your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
;with cte as
(
select id,value1,value2,row_number() over(partition by id order by id) as rn from #t
)

select id,value1,value2 from cte where rn=1
```

## [See Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/14744)

Answer (score 0):

we can do this type also to get required output

```
Select * FROM (
select id,value1,value2,ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Value1)AS RN  from #t

)t
WHERE RN = 1


oR

Select t.ID,t.value1,t.value2 FROM #t t
INNER JOIN (Select  DISTINCT ID,value1,value2 FROM #t GROUP BY id,value1,value2)tt
ON tt.id = t.id AND tt.value1 = t.value1 AND tt.value2 = t.value2
ORDER BY t.value1 ASC,t.value2 ASC
```